# BASH - How to extract data from a column in CSV file and put it in an array?

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

I am learning to script in Bash.

I have a CSV file with 5 columns and 22 rows. I am interested in taking the data from the second column and put it into an array.

What I want is that the first name be in `array[0]`, the second in `array[1]` and so on.

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=","
eCollection=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 MyAssignment.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${eCollection[0]}"
```

The CSV looks like this. There is no line with headers.

The column with the `Vl18xx` numbers is what I want to split into an array.

```
John,Vl1805,VRFname,10.9.48.64/28,10.9.48.78 
John,Vl1806,VRFname,10.9.48.80/28,10.9.48.94
John,Vl1807,VRFname,10.9.48.96/28,10.9.48.110 
John,Vl1808,VRFname,10.9.48.112/28,10.9.48.126
John,Vl1809,VRFname,167.107.152.32/28,167.107.152.46
```

The bash script is not placing the 2nd column into the array, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove your IFS assignment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `IFS=","` assignment thereby letting the default IFS value of space, tab, newline apply

```
#!/bin/bash

eCollection=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 MyAssignment.csv ) )
printf "%s\n" "${eCollection[0]}"
```

Explained: The `eCollection` variable is an array due to the outer parenthesis.  It is initialized with each element from the IFS-separated (think function or command line arguments) words which come from the `$(cut -d ',' -f2 MyAssignment.csv)` subshell, which is the `cut` command used with the `','` delimiter and printing the second field `-f2` from the `MyAssignment.csv` file.

The `printf` statement just shows how to print any item by index, you could also try `echo "${eCollection[@}]}"` to see all of the elements.

Comment: this answer will met with trouble if blank space exist, i.e.:New York

Comment: Won't this break if the CSV has quoted fields with commas inside them?

Comment: Yes, spaces in the fields would be a problem. But the data in the question does not contain spaces. I was shooting for the simplest thing that would work.

Comment: I understand that this answer solves the problem and that why it has so many upvotes but it lacks a proper explanation of the syntax which makes it hard for beginners to learn from it.

Answer (score 11):

Two pure bash solutions:

```
eCollection=()
while IFS=',' read -r _ second _; do
    eCollection+=("$second")
done < file.txt
printf '%s\n' "${eCollection[0]}"
```

```
readarray -t eCollection < file.txt
eCollection=("${eCollection[@]#*,}")
eCollection=("${eCollection[@]%%,*}")
printf '%s\n' "${eCollection[0]}"
```

Comment: Thanks Aleks, I will try your proposed solutions too.

Answer (score 10):

Better is to use `readarray`. No need to mind about IFS which could have any value, and is safe from pathname expansion.

```
readarray -t eCollection < <(cut -d, -f2 MyAssignment.csv)
printf '%s\n' "${eCollection[0]}"
```

Comment: in the end IFS gave me a hard time because of one my columns contained data with blank spaces. I then tried your proposed approach, it worked like a charm! Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

i like to use `awk`. First split based on `,` delimiter and take required column values into array.

```
abc=($(tail -n +1 MyAssignment.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $2;}'))
echo ${abc[1]}
```

Index start from 1. If the file contains headers, replace `+1` with `+2` to ignore headers.