# Extracting data from a column in a CSV file with headers and input into an array in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple bash script that can extract data from one column in csv file and store it as an array. My question is very similar to that of a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669756/bash-how-to-extract-data-from-a-column-in-csv-file-and-put-it-in-an-array), but I am trouble getting the proposed solution from that post to work (possibly because my CSV file has headers).

Specifically, I have a CSV file, `weights.csv`, with two columns:

```
w_neg,w_pos
1.000,1.000
0.523,1.477
0.210,1.790
1.420,0.580
```

and I would like to create an array variable, `w_pos`, that will contain the entire second column of `weights.csv`.

`w_pos=(1.000 1.477 1.790 0.580)`

Based on the answer from [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669756/bash-how-to-extract-data-from-a-column-in-csv-file-and-put-it-in-an-array), I tried to do this using the following line of code:

```
w_pos=( $(cut -d ',' -f2 weights.csv ) )
```

Unfortunately, it seems as if this only stores the first row of `w_pos`. As

```
echo ${w_pos[0]} 
1.000
```

but

```
echo ${w_pos[1]}
```

yields nothing.

I would appreciate any insight into what the problem might be. Ideally, I would like a solution that does not use packages other than what would be bundled with a barebones Unix installation (the script has to run on a cluster that doesn't have simple tools like "bc" :-/)

Comment: This works for me. Also, with your example file `${w_pos[0]}` should be `w_pos` while `${w_pos[1]}` should be `1.000` instead. What do you see for `${w_pos[*]}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `bash`:

```
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2; do
    [[ $col2 =~ ^[0-9] ]] && w_pos+=( $col2 )
done < weights.csv

declare -p w_pos
```

#### Output:

```
declare -a w_pos='([0]="1.000" [1]="1.477" [2]="1.790" [3]="0.580")'
```

- We set the delimiter to `,` by modifying the `IFS`.
- We then read the two columns in two variables
- Append to `w_pos` array variable the second column, if the variable starts with a number. `[[ $col2 =~ ^[0-9] ]]` does that test for us.
- `declare -p` will give you the structure of our array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
w_neg=($(tail -n +2 weights.csv | cut -d, -f1))
w_pos=($(tail -n +2 weights.csv | cut -d, -f2))
```

Comment: This does not work unfortunately. Running echo ${w_neg[@]}$ returns a blank line. Could it be an issue with the csv file?!

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that original code is correct - but somehow does not work for CSV files that were created in MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

i like to use `awk`. Here is an way you can try:

```
w_neg=($(tail -n +2 weights.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $1;}'))
w_pos=($(tail -n +2 weights.csv | awk -F ',' '{print $2;}'))
echo ${w_neg[1]}
echo ${w_pos[1]}
```

index start from 1.