# How do I convert CSV data into an associative array using Bash 4?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, csv, associative-array

The file `/tmp/file.csv` contains the following:

```
name,age,gender
bob,21,m
jane,32,f
```

The CSV file will always have headers.. but might contain a different number of fields:

```
id,title,url,description
1,foo name,foo.io,a cool foo site
2,bar title,http://bar.io,a great bar site
3,baz heading,https://baz.io,some description
```

In either case, I want to convert my CSV data into an array of associative arrays..

### What I need

So, **I want a Bash 4.3 function that takes CSV as piped input and sends the array to stdout:**

/tmp/file.csv:

```
name,age,gender
bob,21,m
jane,32,f
```

**It needs to be used in my templating system, like this**:

`{{foo | csv_to_array | foo2}}`

^ this is a fixed API, I must use that syntax .. `foo2` must receive the array as standard input.

The `csv_to_array` func must do it's thing, so that afterwards I can do this:

```
$ declare -p row1; declare -p row2; declare -p new_array;
```

**and it would give me this**:

```
declare -A row1=([gender]="m" [name]="bob" [age]="21" )
declare -A row2=([gender]="f" [name]="jane" [age]="32" )
declare -a new_array=([0]="row1" [1]="row2")
```

..Once I have this array structure (an indexed array of associative array names), I have a shell-based templating system to access them, like so:

```
{{#new_array}}
  Hi {{item.name}}, you are {{item.age}} years old.
{{/new_array}}
```

But I'm struggling to generate the arrays I need..

### Things I tried:

I have already tried using this as a starting point to get the array structure I need:

```
while IFS=',' read -r -a my_array; do
    echo ${my_array[0]} ${my_array[1]} ${my_array[2]}
done <<< $(cat /tmp/file.csv)
```

(from [Shell: CSV to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704255/shell-csv-to-array?answertab=votes#tab-top))

..and also this:

```
cat /tmp/file.csv | while read line; do
  line=( ${line//,/ } )
  echo "0: ${line[0]}, 1: ${line[1]}, all: ${line[@]}" 
done
```

(from https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1kym4i/bash_create_array_from_one_line_in_csv/cbu9o2o/)

but I didn't really make any progress in getting what I want out the other end...

### EDIT:

Accepted the 2nd answer, but I had to hack the library I am using to make either solution work..

I'll be happy to look at other answers, which *do not export the declare commands as strings, to be run in the current env*, but instead **somehow hoist the resultant arrays of the declare commands to the current env** (the current env is wherever the function is run from).

Example:

```
$ cat file.csv | csv_to_array
$ declare -p row2 # gives the data
```

So, to be clear, if the above ^ works in a terminal, it'll work in the library I'm using without the hacks I had to add (which involved grepping STDIN for `^declare -a` and using `source <(cat); eval $STDIN...` in other functions)...

See my comments on the 2nd answer for more info.

Comment: `if the above ^ works in a terminal` the above will never work in any terminal, as the right side of a pipe is run inside subshell. It's not possible to change environment of parent from a subshell. You have to use some external entity, ex. a temporary file to do that, and read that file (and remove it) in your parent shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script:

```
csv_to_array() {
    local -a values
    local -a headers
    local counter

    IFS=, read -r -a headers
    declare -a new_array=()
    counter=1
    while IFS=, read -r -a values; do
        new_array+=( row$counter )
        declare -A "row$counter=($(
            paste -d '' <(
                printf "[%s]=\n" "${headers[@]}"
            ) <(
                printf "%q\n" "${values[@]}"
            )
        ))"
        (( counter++ ))
    done
    declare -p new_array ${!row*}
}

foo2() {
    source <(cat)
    declare -p new_array ${!row*} |
    sed 's/^/foo2: /'
}

echo "==> TEST 1 <=="

cat <<EOF |
id,title,url,description
1,foo name,foo.io,a cool foo site
2,bar title,http://bar.io,a great bar site
3,baz heading,https://baz.io,some description
EOF
csv_to_array |
foo2 

echo "==> TEST 2 <=="

cat <<EOF |
name,age,gender
bob,21,m
jane,32,f
EOF
csv_to_array |
foo2
```

will output:

```
==> TEST 1 <==
foo2: declare -a new_array=([0]="row1" [1]="row2" [2]="row3")
foo2: declare -A row1=([url]="foo.io" [description]="a cool foo site" [id]="1" [title]="foo name" )
foo2: declare -A row2=([url]="http://bar.io" [description]="a great bar site" [id]="2" [title]="bar title" )
foo2: declare -A row3=([url]="https://baz.io" [description]="some description" [id]="3" [title]="baz heading" )
==> TEST 2 <==
foo2: declare -a new_array=([0]="row1" [1]="row2")
foo2: declare -A row1=([gender]="m" [name]="bob" [age]="21" )
foo2: declare -A row2=([gender]="f" [name]="jane" [age]="32" )
```

The output comes from `foo2` function.

The `csv_to_array` function first reads the headaers. Then for each read line it adds new element into `new_array` array and also creates a new associative array with the name `row$index` with elements created from joining the headers names with values read from the line. On the end the output from `declare -p` is outputted from the function.

The `foo2` function sources the standard input, so the arrays come into scope for it. It outputs then those values again, prepending each line with `foo2:`.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer. It is 99% what I need, but I'd prefer the generated declare stuff is made available to the parent ENV, using `eval` or something, rather than exported out as a string to be sourced/evald.. I am having to add `source <(cat);  
    eval "$STDIN";  
    STDIN="${new_array[@]}";` to the start of the other funcs, but **shouldn't** be allowed (it's a hack)

Comment: To be clear: the "receiving" funcs (`foo2`, `fooX`, etc) all use `read` to set `$STDIN`, which can be `row1 row2 row3`, as long as something like eval and `"echo ${row1[@]}"` can be used to access the array data...

Answer (score 2):

The approach is straightforward:

- Read the column headers into an array
- Read the file line by line, in each line …

  - Create a new associative array and register its name in the array of array names
  - Read the fields and assign them according to the column headers

<sub>In the last step we cannot use `read -a`, `mapfile`, or things like these since they only create regular arrays with numbers as indices, but we want an associative array instead, so we have to create the array manually.</sub>

However, the implementation is a bit convoluted because of bash's quirks.

The following function parses `stdin` and creates arrays accordingly.
I took the liberty to rename your array `new_array` to `rowNames`.

```
#! /bin/bash
csvToArrays() {
    IFS=, read -ra header
    rowIndex=0
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        ((rowIndex++))
        rowName="row$rowIndex"
        declare -Ag "$rowName"
        IFS=, read -ra fields <<< "$line"
        fieldIndex=0
        for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
            printf -v quotedFieldHeader %q "${header[fieldIndex++]}"
            printf -v "$rowName[$quotedFieldHeader]" %s "$field"
        done
        rowNames+=("$rowName")
    done
    declare -p "${rowNames[@]}" rowNames
}
```

Calling the function in a pipe has no effect. Bash executes the commands in a pipe in a subshell, therefore you won't have access to the arrays created by `someCommand | csvToArrays`. Instead, call the function as either one of the following

```
csvToArrays < <(someCommand) # when input comes from a command, except "cat file"
csvToArrays < someFile       # when input comes from a file
```

Bash scripts like these tend to be very slow. That's the reason why I didn't bother to extract `printf -v quotedFieldHeader …` from the inner loop even though it will do the same work over and over again.
I think the whole templating thing and everything related would be way easier to program and faster to execute in languages like python, perl, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks so much... I am so close.. Sorry to be a pain but **I need it working from inside a function**.

And I can't seem to make it work inside a function, piping the CSV to it, which is what I need.

I need to call it like so:

`cat /tmp/file.csv | csv_to_array `

But it wont work - when I change the CSV file, re-run the func, the output of `declare -p` doesn't change... See example:

```
# cat /tmp/file.csv | csv_to_Array
row1 row2

# declare -p row2
bash: declare: row2: not found
```
Any ideas?

(And sorry, stupid SE wont let me add the func I'm using, too long)

Comment: That's because the right-hand side of pipe runs in a subshell (and because my script expects a file, but you used stdin). The arrays only exist inside that subshell. After `csv_to_array` finishes the subshell is closed and all variables are lost. There is no way for the subshell to modify its parent. Here's a solution: Pack my script into a function and change the first assignment to `file="$1"`. Then call `csv_to_array /tmp/file.csv`. That's it. No need for a useless use of cat.

Comment: Still doesn't work .. And I changed the `while read line` to `for line in ..` .. still didn't work..

Comment: And I need the func to work with piped input anyway...  as that is the only input it will ever receive...

Comment: Found the problem. From `help declare`: "*`When used in a function, declare makes NAMEs local, as with the local command. The ‘-g’ option suppresses this behavior.`*". I converted the script into a function that reads stdin for you.

Comment: Thanks but your new functions still has a major problem: I cannot use it how I need to use it (so basically can't use it)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. However, I cannot believe that you cannot use it. Could you add your requirements to your question, for instance "*`I need a function I can use as in <some minimal example code>`*"? In case you have a pipe `cmd1 | ... | cmdN | csvToArrays` write `csvToArrays < <(cmd1 | ... | cmdN)` instead.

Comment: I know, it's very specific .. Sorry!! But it'll be parsed by a custom fork of a mustache-like templating system called `mo`, like so: `{{foo | csv_to_array | where age > 20}}`  <-- this is a fixed API ... I've updated the OP to be clearer. Sorry.